# Android outputStream.write send multiple messages

Tags: android, bluetooth

is there a way to send multiple messages with `OutputStream.write(bytes[])`, for example when i call twice my function to write `func.write("hi"); func.write(" how are you");`, I receive the message "concateneted" like this: `"hi how are you"`, but i want two different messages, is there a way to do it without using separators in my message, i mean know when the other device receives the message, here is my code (its the android bluetooth sample):

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * @param buffer  The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call:

```
mmOutStream.flush()
```

after each message part.

```
public void write(byte[] buffer) {
    try {
        mmOutStream.write(buffer);

        //send what is already in buffer
        mmOutStream.flush();

        // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
        mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                .sendToTarget();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
    }
}
```

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html):

- flush()

> (Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately be written to their intended destination.

Comment: Flush is not solving my issue of concatination. Is there any other solution.

Comment: If you're writing code for the receiving end, maybe add a message terminator byte like a carriage return. Look for that byte on the receive end of your code and you'll know there is a split in between those messages.