# Android OutputStream.write combines multiple messages

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, outputstream

I have an arduino car which I wish to control via Bluetooth from my android phone. I've made an application for this, but when i try to send multiple consecutive messages through my OutputStream.write function, they get sent as a single, concatenated message. For example: if I call connectedThread.write("200-100"); and then connectedThread.write("300-150"), on my serial monitor it shows up as a single message: "200-100300-150". I have seen this same problem in other StackOverflow posts ( [OutputStream.write() never ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086989/outputstream-write-never-ends) , [Android outputStream.write send multiple messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478016/android-outputstream-write-send-multiple-messages) ), but they don't have an answer that works for me, I tried using connectedThread.flush() and it doesn't help. Here is my code (the connecting part is in another Activity, and it works fine):

```
package com.clickau.cosmin.bluetootharduinocarcontroller;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Controls extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SeekBar speed;
    private SeekBar direction;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = DataHolder.getData();
    private ConnectedThread connectedThread;

    private int speedValue;
    private int directionValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_controls);

        speed = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.speed);
        direction = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.direction);
        speedValue = speed.getProgress();
        directionValue = direction.getProgress();

        speed.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser)
            {
                speedValue = speed.getProgress()/5;
                speedValue*=5;
                directionValue = direction.getProgress()/5;
                directionValue*=5;
                /*StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                if (speedValue == 255)
                    str.append("STOP");
                else
                {
                    if (speedValue > 255)
                    {
                        str.append(speedValue - 255);
                        str.append('F');
                    }
                    else if (speedValue < 255)
                    {
                        str.append(255-speedValue);
                        str.append('S');
                    }

                    if (directionValue > 100)
                    {
                        str.append('D');
                        str.append(directionValue-100);
                    }
                    else if (directionValue < 100)
                    {
                        str.append('S');
                        str.append(100 - directionValue);
                    }
                }
                str.append('\n');
                connectedThread.write(str.toString());*/
                connectedThread.write(speedValue+ "+" + directionValue);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {

            }


            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
                speed.setProgress(255);
                speedValue = speed.getProgress();
            }

        });

        direction.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser)
            {
                speedValue = speed.getProgress()/5;
                speedValue*=5;
                directionValue = direction.getProgress()/5;
                directionValue*=5;
                /*StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                if (speedValue == 255)
                    str.append("STOP");
                else
                {
                    if (speedValue > 255)
                    {
                        str.append(speedValue - 255);
                        str.append('F');
                    }
                    else if (speedValue < 255)
                    {
                        str.append(255-speedValue);
                        str.append('S');
                    }

                    if (directionValue > 100)
                    {
                        str.append('D');
                        str.append(directionValue-100);
                    }
                    else if (directionValue < 100)
                    {
                        str.append('S');
                        str.append(100 - directionValue);
                    }
                }
                str.append('\n');
                connectedThread.write(str.toString());*/
                connectedThread.write(speedValue+ "+" + directionValue);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {

            }


            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
                direction.setProgress(100);
                directionValue = direction.getProgress();
            }

        });






        connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        connectedThread.start();

    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread
    {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket)
        {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try{
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            }catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Connected Thread");
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        /*public void run()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            while (true)
            {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1 ,readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }*/

        public void write(String input)
        {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
                mmOutStream.flush();
            } catch(IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this might be an optimization for bluetooth, but it's really annoying because I need those messages to be sent separately when I move the controls, not 10 seconds afterwards. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Very normal problem. That is tcp/ip. How should the receiver know how many bytes are for one message? You should introduce a message separater character or characters or send every command in a line. Or tell in advance how many bytes the following message will be. Dont panic. You are #123456 with this problem. You will solve it.

Comment: `mmOutStream.flush();` That should normally be enough for promt delivery.

Comment: Yes, it worked, I added a '\n' character and modified the arduino code so that it reads until it finds that character. But now I have another problem: in the serial monitor it sometimes shows question marks instead of numbers.

Comment: Solved that problem too, I had to put an if statement which verifies if there is any data available before i read a char in my arduino code, or else it would be set to null. Thank you for help!

Comment: `You will solve it.` And you did!